# Why do my threads randomly die without throwing any exceptions?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm just trying out some basic threading in Python, but when I run this program, over a small amount of time, two of the three threads will randomly die and throw no exceptions. I don't understand what's going on. I have a brand new computer and this is a fresh 2.7.5 install...

```
import threading
import time
import random

class Thr(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Thr, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.go()
        except:
            print "***FAIL***"

    def go(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            print self.name

class Prog:

    def __init__(self):
        print "hey"
        self.t1 = Thr("One ")
        self.t1.start()
        self.t2 = Thr("Two ")
        self.t2.start()
        self.t3 = Thr("Three ")
        self.t3.start()

Prog()
```

Comment: How long does it take for the threads to die? Sitting here, watching and all live well :)

Comment: Perhaps it's because you `import random` but don't do anything with it... :P

Comment: Sometimes it happens basically instantly, other times it takes a minute to die. And also I was mucking with the code a bit and I was using random in the sleep argument, but I removed it before posting the code and forgot to take out the import.

Comment: Could you append the *sysout* from your terminal?